# What does $\sigma(A_n)$ look like?

Tags: measure-theory

> > Let $\Omega=\mathbb{N}$, $A_n:=\left\{\left\{1\right\},\left\{2\right\},\ldots,\left\{n\right\}\right\}$.
> >     What does then $\sigma(A_n)$ (generated $\sigma$-Algebra) look like?

Surely, $\mathbb{N}\in\sigma(A_n)$ and $A_n\in\sigma(A_n)$. But which sets are in $\sigma(A_n)$, too?

Unions and complements, okay. But how can I determine them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $0 \leq k\leq n$, define
$$
\mathcal{A}_k = \{B \subset \{1,2,\ldots, n\} : |B| = k\}
$$
and set
$$
\mathcal{A} = \bigcup_{k=0}^n \{B : B\in \mathcal{A}_k, \text{ or } B^c \in \mathcal{A}_k\}
$$
Clearly, any $\sigma$-algebra containing $A_n$ must contain $\mathcal{A}$, so it suffices to prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

The only non-trivial thing to check is that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under countable unions. So suppose $B_1, B_2 \ldots$ are in $\mathcal{A}$, and
$$
B = \cup B_j
$$
Then you have two choices, either $|B| < \infty$ or $|B| = +\infty$.

If $|B|<\infty$, each $B_j \in \mathcal{A}_k$, and so $B \in \mathcal{A}_{k_0}$ where $k_0$ would be the max of those $k$'s.

If $|B| = +\infty$, then there must be a $B_j$ such that $|B_j| = +\infty$ (why?), but then
$$
|B_j^c| \leq n \Rightarrow |B^c| \leq n \Rightarrow B \in \mathcal{A}
$$

Given all this, you can actually "write down" all the elements of $\mathcal{A}_k$, and thus all the elements of $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: But why so complicated? I just get $\sigma(A_n)=\left\{A\subset\mathbb{N}: A\subset\left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}\text{ or }A^C\subset\left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}\right\}$.

Comment: @math12 : That's exactly the same thing! The work is in showing that it is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: (1) $\left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}\in\sigma(A_n)\Rightarrow\sigma(A_n)\neq\emptyset$, (2) $A\in\sigma(A_n)\Rightarrow (A^C)^C=A\in\sigma(A_n)$ and (3) $(B_n)_{n\geq 1}\in\sigma(A_n)^{\mathbb{N}}$, then consider two cases: 1. $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}B_n\subset\left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}\Rightarrow \bigcup_{n\geq 1}B_n\in\sigma(A_n)$. 2. $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}B_n\notin\sigma(A_n)\Rightarrow \exists j: B_j$ is not subset of $\left\{1,\dots,n\right\}$. Then $B_j^C\subset\left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}$. Then $(\bigcup_{n\geq 1}B_n)^C=\bigcap_{n\geq 1}B_n^C\subseteq B_j^C\subset\left\{1,\dots,n\right\}$ - Right?